# Using R to filter through several different files

Tags: r, function, dplyr, filtering, tidyverse

I am looking to create a function that searches a column for a specific value we'll say "ID". I was able to create a function that searches for one file, but I want it to keep going through and compile all records/observations where the filter is TRUE.

so far I have

```
ID_search <- function(ID_num){
                 DATA.1 %>% filter(ID == "ID_num")
}
```

After it completes it's search in one file I want it to keep looking in the other files, say DATA.2, DATA.3 and so on and then eventually prints out every record/observation that it finds. It would be nice to also have it return that "No records found in Data.X" and then continue it's search and do this process until it's checked all files. I am fairly new to R, so still trying to figure stuff out. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: (1) You cannot use the variable `ID_num` and a string `"ID_num"` like that, look into NSE or programmatic use of `dplyr` and friends; (2) it's bad practice to use `DATA.1` in this sense, as it makes this function completely dependent on the calling environment and therefore not perfectly reproducible (same output given the same input(s)), consider making the data a function argument; (3) what about `x$ID == ID_num` (returning a logical vector), `which(x$ID == ID_num)` (integer vector, 0 or longer), or the regex variants `grepl(ID_num, x$ID)` and `grep(...)` don't work for you?

Comment: Without a reproducible example I can't give specific advice. However, If all your files are in one folder, you can get a character vector containing all the file names using `list.files`. You can then use the `lapply` function to iterate over all of the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll illustrate the subsetting process with `lapply()` and the [Pokémon Stats](https://github.com/lgreski/pokemonData) data, which consists of one comma separated values file for each of seven generations of Pokémon.

```
download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/pokemonData/master/pokemonData.zip",
              "pokemonData.zip",
              method="curl",mode="wb")
unzip("pokemonData.zip")
```

Next, we read the list of data files to be processed, then use `lapply()` with an anonymous function and a second argument, `y`, to subset on the `Type1` stat.

```
thePokemonFiles <- list.files("./pokemonData",pattern = ".csv",
                              full.names=TRUE)
pokemonDataFiles <- lapply(thePokemonFiles,function(x,y) {
     data <- read.csv(x,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
     aSubset <- data[data$Type1 == y,]
     if (nrow(aSubset) == 0) message("No pokemon of type1 = ",y,
                                     " in ",x)
     else aSubset

},"Flying")
```

The function writes messages for the files that have no Pokémon with `Type1` of `Flying`.

```
No pokemon of type1 = Flying in ./pokemonData/gen01.csv
No pokemon of type1 = Flying in ./pokemonData/gen02.csv
No pokemon of type1 = Flying in ./pokemonData/gen03.csv
No pokemon of type1 = Flying in ./pokemonData/gen04.csv
No pokemon of type1 = Flying in ./pokemonData/gen07.csv
```

Finally, we bind the data and print the first few rows of Pokémon whose `Type1` stat is `Flying`.

```
data <- do.call(rbind,pokemonDataFiles)    
head(data)
```

...and the output:

```
head(data)
    Number                    Name  Type1  Type2 Total HP Attack Defense
150    641 TornadusIncarnate Forme Flying          580 79    115      70
151    641   TornadusTherian Forme Flying          580 79    100      80
73     714                  Noibat Flying Dragon   245 40     30      35
74     715                 Noivern Flying Dragon   535 85     70      80
    SpecialAtk SpecialDef Speed Generation Legendary
150        125         80   111          5      True
151        110         90   121          5      True
73          45         40    55          6     False
74          97         80   123          6     False
```